# android / phonegap app multiple screen support

Tags: android, html, cordova

We are developing a mobile application for the android platform using html5,CSS3, JQM and phonegap.
since there are varied screen sizes available among android phones  , we are not able to find a way to fit the background images or any images in multiple screens. The background images would fit decently in say HTC One V , Samsung S3 mini but would fail to stretch in bigger phones like Samsung Note etc

the approaches we have used

1. We  have used images of resolution 320*480 for the mdpi, hdpi , xhdpi folders and  using CSS3 , we are trying to stretch them in bigger screens if required.
   The CSS used :

   /*  bkground image for each screen */

   ## welcomePage{

   ```
       background:url('file:///android_res/drawable/back_welcome_2x.png') no-repeat center center;
   background-attachment:fixed;
   min-height:100%;
   background-size:cover;
   ```

   }

   - This does not work.
2. we have tried to change the viewport metadata by inserting width=device-width , height=device-height, initial scale=1.0 , target-dpi=device-dpi and using an image of 528*909 ( for instance) . This cuts the image a little but fits the screen. At the same time, all the jquery mobile components in the UI are reduced in size. We are not sure if this is the right approach.

For targetting as many screen sizes as possible, which is the parameter to be considered? the screen size, the resolution, or the DPI?

What exactly can we do to make sure our background images fit for almost all android phones screens ( like the samsung Note).

Or can you tell if we can improvise on either approach 1 ot 2?

Answer (score 0):

**I assume your background image is not a tile.**

Do not stretch images too much. It will make your images look blurry or unsharp. As with a native Android app, ship the background image in multiple resolutions. You can then choose the correct image very simply using [a handlebars helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/) as I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177134/supporting-multiple-resolution-and-density-of-images-in-phonegap/16769241#16769241).

**Javascript:**

```
if (screen.width <= 480) {
    imgFolder = 'img/low/';
}
else {
    imgFolder = 'img/high/';
}

Handlebars.registerHelper('imgFolder', function () {
    return imgFolder
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<body style="background:url('{{imgFolder}}yourImage.png'); background-size:cover;" />
```

Of course, you have to add resolutions for ldpi/mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi - which I dont know currently. I do not think you can use androids internal size-adjustment mechanism using googles `dp` value (which is something else than `dpi`) in a browser, so your best option is to use the 4 most common resolutions (e.g. widths of 320, 480, 600, 800 - I might be wrong) and downscale images for intermediate resolutions.

For Android, it is common to use 4 image folders:

- ldpi
- hdpi
- mdpi
- xhdpi

Although they have dpi in their name, this is not the parameter you should look at. As a parameter for determining resolutions, you should use `screen.width` - after you have checked that your pg app/cordova browser has 1:1 pixel mapping. You do that by using the following:

```
alert('screen size: ' + screen.width + ' x ' + screenheight + ' browser size: ' + $(window).width() + ' x ' + $(window).height());
```

The `width` and `height` of `window` have to match the values of `screen`. Otherwise, your images are scaled and will not look good - and your app will look much worse than a native one (except the very uncommon situatioin of not using any pixel based (.png/.jpg) images). You can fix the mapping using media queries, which can be a little fiddly.

After you have accomplished a 1:1 pixel mapping you can use `screen.width` (You will have to compare `screen.width` and `screen.height` and take the smaller value if your app supports both landscape and portrait orientation). If 1:1 mapping is for some reason not possible (worst case that should be avoided at all costs), use `window.innerWidth` or `$(window).width()`.
Your jqm behaviour(reduced size when using the meta tags you provided) could indicate that your pixel mapping is not as accurate as it could be.

The scaling ratios for all your images are

```
3:4:6:8 (ldpi:mdpi:hdpi:xhdpi)
```