# Support multiple resolution Images in Phone gap with different size

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, cordova

I've develop a Phonegap App and I've a problem to resize the image as per Android Device(set width and Height). As device Height and Width change I want to change my image size. I 've use below link for that but it does not work [supporting multiple resolution and density of images in phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177134/supporting-multiple-resolution-and-density-of-images-in-phonegap)
My code is as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Worklist</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if(window.devicePixelRatio == 0.75) {
           $("#dIcon_notification").attr('src', '/images/mpdi/my_notification_new.png');   
        }
        else if(window.devicePixelRatio == 1) {
           $("#dIcon_notification").attr('src', '/images/mdpi/my_notification_new.png');  
        }
        else if(window.devicePixelRatio == 1.5) {
           $("#dIcon_notification").attr('src', '/images/hpdi/my_notification_new.png');   
        }
        else if(window.devicePixelRatio == 2) {
           $("#dIcon_notification").attr('src', '/images/hpdi/my_notification_new.png');  
        }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" data-theme="f"> 


    <div class="ui-header ui-bar-a" role="banner" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1 style="white-space:pre-wrap" aria-level="1" role="heading" tabindex="0" class="ui-title" >Smart Self Service</h1>
    </div><!--/header-->

<div data-role="content"  data-theme="f">

        <div id="center_content" >
        <div id="dashboard">
            <a href="Notification.html" data-ajax="false" ><img id="dIcon_notification" display="inline"  src="images/hdpi/my_notification_new.png" class="dashaboard_icon" alt="" ></a>
            <a href="#" ><img id="dIcon_request" src="images/hdpi/new_request_new.png" class="dashaboard_icon" alt="" ></a>
            <a href="#" ><img id="dIcon_setting" src="images/hdpi/setting.png"        class="dashaboard_icon" alt="" ></a>
            <a href="#" ><img id="dIcon_exit" src="images/hdpi/exit.png"               class="dashaboard_icon" alt="" ></a>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

I am new to Jquery and CSS so every help will be appreciable. I want to solve it. please Help

Comment: Please Guide me If I've made mistake anywhere.

Comment: In your HTML, the image paths start with `images` whereas in your JavaScript they are `/images`. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Hii @ville thnks for reply. but It doesn't effect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you used will work for different resolutions. like normal and retina display. If you want to change image sizes according to device sizes(but same resolutions) you can use CSS 3 media queries and apply different css on different size devices.

your css will go under something like this-

```
 @media screen and (min-device-width : 480px) and (max-device-width : 854px){
//css for devices whose width is more than 480px but less than 854px
}
```

you can use combination of width and resolution media queries as well.

Please search for adaptive web design and media queries you will get a lot of stuff.